# javax.swing.JList<String> don't refresh with Apache Cassandra data

Tags: java, swing, cassandra, twitter4j

I'm trying to display data from a Apache Cassandra database. I have this code:

```
    private void jButtonTimelineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    List<Row> l = cassandra.queryTimeline();
    JList<String> listaTweets= new JList<String>();

    for(Row r : l) {        
       JLabel label = new JLabel(r.getString(3));  
       System.out.println(r.getString(3));
       jList1.add(label);
    }
    jList1.revalidate();
    jList1.repaint();
}
```

I have tried many things and the UI don't display the labels. I'm sure that the list of Rows is correct. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to add components to a `JList`?  This isn't how it works.  You add data to a `ListModel` and use a `ListCellRenderer` to determine how they are rendered. I'd think you'd be better off starting with [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have post an unfinished code. its hard to to understand thses type of code. though i have something in my mind. hope this works.

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> jList1 = new JList<>( model );
```

now add those items to "model" like this

```
model.addElement(lavel.getString());
```

no need to add these codes jList1.revalidate();
    jList1.repaint();